anchor build fails with 'no such command: `build-sbf`', but I can see build-sbf is installed
I've installed Rust, Solana 1.18 (currently in beta) and Anchor 0.30.
On a new project:
anchor init project
cd project
anchor build

fails with:
error: no such command: `build-sbf`

    View all installed commands with `cargo --list`
    Find a package to install `build-sbf` with `cargo search cargo-build-sbf`

Running cargo --list does not show build-sbf installed.
However if I run ls -la ~/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin I can see the file exists:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 someuser somegroup 21154624 Mar  3 06:33 cargo-build-sbf

My understanding is that cargo-build-sbf is the file that actually gets run when cargo build-sbf is ran. Eg I can do  ~/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/cargo-build-sbf --version and cargo build-sbf --version and see the same output.
How can I make build-sbf appear in cargo --list?

What do you see when you do solana --version? On many unix systems the Solana tools don't properly add themselves to the shell config and you need to edit your ./zshrc or ./bash

@Whiteseal thanks for the help but I've solved it. See below.

So per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78374309/why-is-my-installed-command-not-showing-in-cargo-list cargo --list shows binaries using $PATH.
Per the Cargo docs:

3rd party subcommands (ie. programs named cargo-foobar placed in $PATH)...

For most users (ie, using a regular terminal and not GitHub actions)
You probably need to add Solana to your PATH, ie:
export PATH=~/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin:$PATH

And add a line like this in ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc to make it permanent.
For GitHub Actions users
In my case (I was using GitHub Actions), though the directory was in PATH, GitHub actions behaves differently to bash, and does not expand ~ when adding directories to PATH. Copying the solution from that answer:
Failing:
- name: Install Solana CLI (beta)
  run: |
    sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/beta/install)"
    echo "~/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH

Working
- name: Install Solana CLI (beta)
  run: |
    sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/beta/install)"
    echo "/home/runner/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH

...solves the problem.

Adding to what @mikemaccana suggested, you may need to find the path containing your solana cli bin and add it to PATH. I was running on github's codespace, so i only needed to run this which added that path to PATH.
export PATH=/home/codespace/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/:$PATH

It resets after you log out, so you can add it to your .bashrc file.

export PATH=~/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin:$PATH
might interfere with other python setups on your machine. This works better for me
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin
